# Hide directive not working properly on IE

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11

**Issue:**

I have my Angular 2 app Form with some hidden error messages (I use Angular 2 native validation, nothing special), the thing is... some of the errors keep hidden on IE 11 but some of them show up, I can't figure out wheres the problem since its the only browser with this particular problem.

Here's example of one of the errors that are behaving like this and one screenshot.

PS. Already tried changing the `[hidden]` for `ngIf` but no results.

Code with an error working:

```
        <div class="form__item">
            <input              
            name="lastname" #lastname="ngModel"
            class="form__field form__has-border-top-tick" type="text" 
            placeholder="APELLIDOS*" required maxlength="200"
            [(ngModel)]="user.lastname" 
            [class.form__field--error]="lastname.errors && lastname.touched">

            <div *ngIf="lastname.errors && (lastname.dirty || lastname.touched)">
                <div [hidden]="!lastname.errors.required" class="error__message">
                    El apellido es obligatorio  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Code Related to the Issue:

```
        <div class="form__item">
            <input              
                name="email" class="form__field" type="email" 
                placeholder="CORREO ELECTRÓNICO*" required
                [(ngModel)]="user.email" #email="ngModel"
                [class.form__field--error]="email.errors && email.touched"  
                (blur)="validateEmail()" maxlength="200"
                pattern="^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,3})+$">  

            <div *ngIf="email.errors && (email.dirty || email.touched)">
                <div [hidden]="!email.errors.required" class="error__message">
                    El email es obligatorio
                </div>
                
                <div [hidden]="!email.errors.pattern" class="error__message">
                    El formato del correo electrónico es inválido
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
```